# Regular expression for anchor tag in c#

Tags: c#, regex

My anchor tag looks like this:-

```
    <a href="/as" title="asd" page="as" name="asd" reference="Yes" type="relativepath">as
</a>
```

I tried in this way:-

```
 <a [^>]*?>(?<text>.*?)</a>
```

It is working fine when the ending anchor tag `</a>` supposed to be in the same line. 
But in my case the ending anchor tag should come in next line.

I need a regular expression that it should supports, if the ending anchor tag  is in the next line.

Suggestions welcome.

Comment: Obligatory: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/219661

Comment: You shouldn't be parsing HTML with Regex. Use the HTML Agility Pack https://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 2):

You should use the `(?s)` inline option:

```
(?s)<a [^>]*?>(?<text>.*?)</a>
```

See [demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3Fs)%3Ca%20%5B%5E%3E%5D*%3F%3E(%3F%3Ctext%3E.*%3F)%3C%2Fa%3E&i=%20%3Ca%20href%3D%22%2Fas%22%20title%3D%22asd%22%20page%3D%22as%22%20name%3D%22asd%22%20reference%3D%22Yes%22%20type%3D%22relativepath%22%3Eas%0D%0A%3C%2Fa%3E).

In C#, you can also use `RegexOptions.Singleline` option the following way:

```
var input = "<a href=\"/as\" title=\"asd\" page=\"as\" name=\"asd\" reference=\"Yes\" type=\"relativepath\">as\r\n</a>";
var regex = new Regex(@"<a [^>]*?>(?<text>.*?)</a>", RegexOptions.Singleline);
var result2 = regex.Match(input).Value;
```

Output:

[image]

**EDIT:**

This is an updated version of the regex that takes into account `<a>` tags that do not have attributes (which is next to impossible, but let's imagine :)), and also make it case-insensitive (who knows, maybe `<A HREF="SOMETHING_HERE">`  can also occur):

```
var regex = new Regex(@"(?i)<a\b[^>]*?>(?<text>.*?)</a>", RegexOptions.Singleline);
```

Comment: Thanks for your help.Its working.

Answer (score 0):

Just use DOTALL modifier which makes the DOT present in your regex to match even line breaks.

```
@"(?s)<a [^>]*?>(?<text>.*?)</a>"
```

OR

You could use negated character class.

```
@"<a [^>]*?>(?<text>[^<>]*)</a>"
```

Comment: Without `?`, it would match from the first opening `a` tag upto the last closing closing `a` tag.

Comment: Oh, sorry. It is the greedy operator of course. My bad.